# Relative positioning

Tags: css, html

I read an article on relative and static positioning at [w3c](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning). I have tried this on my database form and with some adjustments using percentages in place of ems, I have it working in Chrome and IE 11, but not Firefox.  I was not too confident with ems, although I realize it is a relative measurement in itself.

Can anyone comment on the veracity of this article in terms of being up-to-date? In compliance with html5?  Or, otherwise you're general thoughts about the article?

The form contains many tables, rows, and cells, which might explain (from what I have read) the problem with Firefox.  Although, I have all of those elements contained within a div on which the relative positioning is applied.  If helpful I can supply code sample, or a url where the beast might be examined.

Comment: Please do supply a URL to a demo, preferably only the problematic parts.

Comment: The article is up-to-date, it was last updated on June 4 2013 (see [the edit history](http://www.w3.org/wiki/index.php?title=CSS_static_and_relative_positioning&action=history)). Also, see [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Gecko_notes) which discusses FF-specific bugs.

Comment: I've been sanitizing for the past 30min or so.
http://asbs.zapto.org/clarity3/testRelativePos.html

Comment: I should mention I used Olsson's nav and sidebar as the model in my application, since I have two columns.  In the css items 6, 7, and 8 provide the definitions for positioning, etc, of the rightCol, leftCol, and wrapper.